# Loading a text file using File Chooser then using Scanner JavaFX

Tags: javafx, filechooser

I am trying to load in a text file using File Chooser. I then need to use a scanner on the file because I am tokenizing the strings. Before I hardcoded the file names with the files being in my project file but now I want to be able to get the files needed from anywhere.

My current code

```
public void LoadCustomer() throws IOException
{
    Stage stages = new Stage();
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stages);
    File CustomerList;
    CustomerList = new File(fileChooser.getInitialDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    String line;
    String tokens[];
    int iTemp;
    String strTemp;
    Double dTemp;

    int i20DTemp;
    Customer cTemp;
    try {
        Scanner inputCustomer = new Scanner(CustomerList);
        while (inputCustomer.hasNextLine())
```

I think my problem is some where around the `CustomerList = new File` area since thats were my code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The file the user chooses is returned by [`fileChooser.showOpenDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-javafx.stage.Window-). [`getInitialDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#getInitialDirectory--) just returns the directory that the `FileChooser` initially shows. If no value was assigned, `null` is returned which causes an exception, since you try to call a method of that object.

```
File CustomerList = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stages);
if (CustomerList == null) {
    // user canceled dialog
} else {
    // file was selected
}
```

By the way: You can also pass `null` to the `showOpenDialog` method. Creating a new `Stage` for that purpose is not required (nor would I recommend doing it, even if you use the `Stage` later).